# $A=12.3$ and let $B=\dfrac{25}{2}$. What $C$, as a decimal to the nearest hundredth, if $C$ is three-quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On the number line, let $A=12.3$ and let $B=\dfrac{25}{2}$. What is the value of $C$, as a decimal to the nearest hundredth, if $C$ is three-quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$?

So $A=12.3$ and $B=12.5$. We see that $B-A=0.2$ and three quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$ would put us at $12.45$ since three-quarters of $0.2$ is $0.05$ and three of them gives us $0.15$ which is added $A$ for $A+0.15=12.3+0.15=12.45$. How does this look? Does this make sense or am I totally wrong? It says the decimal needs to be to the nearest hundredth.

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}$

Comment: @Raffaele I'm not sure. Three quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$ makes me think $C$ is in the interval $(A,B)$. Maybe someone else can clear this up for us.

Comment: I'd first find the number 3/4 of the way from $10A$ to $10B$, then divide by 10.

Answer (score 0):

[image: graph]

The distance between $A$ and $B$ equals

$$\begin{align}
B-A &= \frac{25}{2}-12.3 \\
&= 12.5-12.3 \\
&= 0.2 \\
\end{align}$$

Thus “three quarters of the way from $A$ to $B$” equals

$$\begin{align}
A+\frac{3(B-A)}{4} &= 12.3 + \frac{3(0.2)}{4} \\
&= 12.3 +\frac{0.6}{4} \\
&= 12.3 + \frac{0.3}{2} \\
&= 12.3 + 0.15 \\
&= 12.45 \\
\end{align} $$

Thus you were spot on!

A general formula you could use for point $P$ a fraction $f$ of the way to the positive direction on the number line would be $$P=A+f\left|A-B\right|$$

You can switch $A$ and $B$ inside the modulus bars, and to go a fraction $f$ of the way in the negative direction, from $B$, use $$P=B-f\left|A-B\right|$$

These assume $B>A$.